# Swift 4. iOS 13. UIButton inside a UITableViewCell - how to touch and scroll?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am going to create a dictionary app with a list of words and their translations. My idea is next - when to click / touch the word (text on the UIButton) - the word will be voiced. But I see the issue with scrolling the UITableView - I can scroll it only if I touch the delimiter between table rows

```
let srollView = UIScrollView()
let tableRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: listContentWidth, height: listContentHeight)
myTableView = UITableView(frame: tableRect, style: UITableView.Style.plain)
myTableView.register(ListTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId) //Registration of my Custom ListTableViewCell
myTableView.dataSource = self
myTableView.delegate = self
myTableView.delaysContentTouches = true;
myTableView.canCancelContentTouches = true;
srollView.addSubview(myTableView)
```

How to use UIButtons inside of the UITableViewCell. which I create programmatically:

```
class ListTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
  private let textBtn: UIButton = {
    let btn = UIButton()
    //...
    return btn
  }()
  private let translationBtn: UIButton = {
    let btn = UIButton()
    //...
    return btn
  }()
  override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [
        textBtn,
        translationBtn
    ])
    stackView.alignment = .fill
    stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    stackView.spacing = 5
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    //...
    addSubview(stackView)
  }
  
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to put a table view in a scroll view?

Comment: because it will contain a long list of rows. And I will have a top bar with buttons and a bottom bar with buttons

Answer (score 0):

You need to add target for that button.

```
textBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yourFunction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

And of course you need to set tag of that button since you are using it.

```
textBtn.tag = indexPath.row
```

To get the tag in your function:

```
@objc func yourFunction(sender: UIButton){
    let buttonTag = sender.tag
}
```

Some things to consider:

1. You need to add the subview to the cells **contentView** and not to the cell itself.
2. Cells are being reused: so subclass **UITableViewCell** and add the button to its initializer.